# CMake: Howto modify a variable from inside a function

Tags: function, cmake

What is the best practice to modify a caller's variable from inside a CMake-function.
Assume

```
function(MyFunction IN_OUT_NAME)

   ... what to do here ...

   string(APPEND ${IN_OUT_NAME} " and that")

   ... what to do here ...

endfunction()
```

What needs to be done such that the following code fragment

```
set(MY_MESSAGE "this")
MyFunction(MY_MESSAGE)
message(${MY_MESSAGE})
```

delivers

```
this and that
```

Not-a-duplicate-remarks:

- [Modify a variable inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978392/modify-a-variable-inside-a-function) is about JavaScript not CMake
- [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) is about JavaScript not CMake

Comment: set(variable ${varaible} PARENT_SCOPE) ?

Comment: Well, that sets it. But how can I read it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `PARENT_SCOPE` to export the value to parent scope:

```
function(MyFunction IN_OUT_NAME)
    string(APPEND ${IN_OUT_NAME} " and that")
    set(${IN_OUT_NAME} "${${IN_OUT_NAME}}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
    
set(MY_MESSAGE "this")
MyFunction(MY_MESSAGE)
message(${MY_MESSAGE})
```

Alternate way, available since CMake 3.25 - use [`return(PROPAGATE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/command/return.html):

```
function(MyFunction IN_OUT_NAME)
    string(APPEND ${IN_OUT_NAME} " and that")
    return(PROPAGATE ${IN_OUT_NAME})
endfunction()
```

Comment: Important this ( Pre 3.25, have not tested the return() ) does not work when calling the function with an variable who's name is the same as the function parameter, in this case `IN_OUT_NAME`. 
`set( IN_OUT_NAME "Test2" )` +`MyFunction( IN_OUT_NAME )` won't modify the variable, this can come up in functions which use each other.