# D3: Passing extra arguments to attr functions inside a selection.join()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've some code inside a `selection.join()` pattern:

```
const nodeWidth = (node) => node.getBBox().width;

const toolTip = selection
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .join(
      (enter) => {

        const g = enter
          .append('g')

        g.append('text')
          .attr('x', 17.5)
          .attr('y', 10)
          .text((d) => d.text);
       
        let offset = 0;
        g.attr('transform', function (d) {
          let x = offset;
          offset += nodeWidth(this) + 10;
          return `translate(${x}, 0)`;
        });

        selection.attr('transform', function (d) {
          return `translate(${
            (0 - nodeWidth(this)) / 2
          },${129.6484} )`;
        });
      },

      (update) => {
        
        update
          .select('text')
          .text((d) => d.text);

        let offset = 0;
        update.attr('transform', function (d) {
          let x = offset;
          offset += nodeWidth(this) + 10;
          return `translate(${x}, 0)`;
        });

        selection.attr('transform', function (d) {
          return `translate(${
            (0 - nodeWidth(this)) / 2
          },${129.6484} )`;
        });
      }
    );
```

as you can see, in the `enter` and `update` section I need to call a couple of functions to calculate several nodes transformations. In particular, the code stores in the accumulation var `offset` the length of the previous text element. This properly spaces text elements (ie, text0 <- 10 px -> text1 <- 10 px -> ...).

As you can see, the "transform functions" in the `enter` and `update` section are identical. I'm trying to define them just in one place and call them where I need. E.g.,

```
   (update) => {
     update.attr('transform', foo);

     selection.attr('transform', bar);
    }
```

However, I cannot refactor the code this way because it looks like I cannot pass in neither the `offset` value nor `this` to the function passed to `attr()`.

Is there a way to do it?

EDIT:

As per Gerardo Furtado's hint (if I got it right), you can define `foo` as follows:

```
const foo = function(d, i, n, offset) {
          let x = offset;
          offset += nodeWidth(n[i]) + 10;
          return `translate(${x}, 0)`;
}
```

then in the `selection.join¡` you have to call `foo` this way:

```
   (update) => {
     let offset = 0;
     update.attr('transform', (d, i, n) => foo(d, i, n, offset));

    }
```

However, refactoring this way, offset is ever equal to 0. A possibile solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21978425/4820341

Comment: You use `selection.attr("transform"` for both the update and the enter: since you use this twice, you overwrite the transform set the first time. Also, as your offset value starts at 0 for the update and the enter selections, your update should be overtop your enter - am I missing something there? (eg: are you never entering new elements after the initial enter?)

Comment: Regarding the `this`, it's being passed, check again. Regarding `offset` that has nothing to do with D3, that's a Javascript feature: the scope of a function depends on where it is defined, not where you call it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yep, indeed the challenge is using the same function without repeating it

Comment: @floatingpurr that's not a challenge at all, just pass `offset` as an argument.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I might be wrong, but I cannot pass the offset this way inside attr(). If you have a working solution, please submit your answer. Happy to accept it. Thanx!

Comment: It's just `update.attr('transform', (d, i, n) => foo(d, i, n, offset));`, and then `selection.attr('transform', (d, i, n) => foo(d, i, n, offset));`, etc. Inside `foo` you get `this` as `n[i]` and `offset` as `offset`, obviously.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado. Tried this way but I cannot modify the offset value in the scope where foo is called (more in the original post)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Function.prototype.bind().

```
const doSomething = (d) => {
    return `translate(${
        (0 - nodeWidth(this)) / 2
    },${129.6484} )`;
}
```

Calling the function inside (enter) and (update)

```
selection.attr('transform', doSomething.bind(d));
```

This way the function gets executed in the current scope.

I guess this is what you are looking for. Please be aware that I could not test my code!

Comment: Working this way I get 'd is not defined'. Also the offset is not managed anymore.

Comment: @floatingpurr sorry, my fault. cal() will actually call the function in the scope, you have to use .bind() which returns a function in the scope, because selection.attr() needs a function, not the return value. I updated my code.

Comment: The offset makes this more complicated. This is why I chose the other duplicated method. You may have to introduce another function including the offet, but without testing this I may not be able to find a solution. Sorry.

Comment: Bind will also result in d being undefined. selection.attr() already passes `d` (current datum) and `this` (current node) (and also passes other parameters) to the supplied function with Function.apply(), there is no need to use bind or call. The offset is the challenge.

Comment: @Wolfgang, no worries. However, still getting 'd is not defined'

Comment: @AndrewReid, I did not know that `this` is passed. I believed that selection.attr() passes just `d`, and `i`(ie., datum and index)

Comment: @floatingpurr,, `this` within the supplied function refers to the current node ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr)) of course `this` will be different when using an arrow function. I'll take a closer look at the question in a bit.