# making javascript variables keep their value

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and I was wondering if anyone could help me for what seems to be quite a simple question to anyone who knows anything about JS. My problem is that I am trying to change the value of my variables after declaring them but everytime I change their values they are set back to what they used to be when they got declared. If anyone could please explain how I could work my way around this problem it would be greatly appreciated, Here's my code if you want to see it:

```
//Anything before this doesn't matter for my question.
                          <td>
                            <p id="first"></p> <--- this prints the "first" var declared in the script bellow but is always equal to 1 even when the button is pressed
                          </td>
                          <th class="col-xs-1 align-middle text-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-add-all" onclick="value_up(first);"> <--- this is the button that calls the function when pressed
                                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <script>
                            var first = 1; <--- this is where I declare my variable
                            document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = first; <--- Here's where I pass my variable to the <p> tags up above
                        </script>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function value_up(x) { <--- this is the function I am calling when I press the up button
            x = x - 1;
            console.log(x);
            return (x);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: do you need to use pure html/js or can you use an external library like svelte, vue, or angular?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify a variable inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978392/modify-a-variable-inside-a-function)

Comment: I only have access to pure HTML and JS so I can't use any external libraries

Comment: FYI updating a js variable will not automatically update your HTML.

Comment: `value_up(first)` and then `x = x - 1` doesn't make any sense

Comment: HTML is not reactive, you will need to update the DOM manually.

Comment: It's called value up because I am printing numbers in ascending order so if you press the button up, the value of first should go down to be smaller than what is already there

Comment: enzo it might, I will try it right now, thanks

Comment: A couple of notes: [1] your `value_up()` function does not update the content of your `<p id="first"></p>` tag. [2] Some browsers create a global variable for each element with an ID, therefore it is better to avoid using "first" for both your paragraph ID and variable name, as it might generate a conflict.

Comment: alright thanks for the tips I never used Javascript before so everything you guys are telling me is greatly helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning `x` but never setting `first` to `x`. As such, `first` never changes. Values are passed in by value in javascript and so you need to change the value of `first` directly instead of just passing it in.
You also need to reupdate the value that your HTML element holds. Please check the following example:

```js
let first = 0
document.getElementById("first-val").innerHTML = first;
let increment_first = () =>{
  first += 1
  document.getElementById("first-val").innerHTML = first;
 
}
```

```html
<p> Value of first: <span id="first-val"></span></p>
<button onclick="increment_first()">Increment!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help, it's all good now!

Answer (score 1):

To be slightly more robust pass the id and then get/set using the passed id

```js
var first = 1; 
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = first;

function value_up(id) {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).textContent)
  x+=1 // or whatever operation you want
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = x
}
```

```html
<p id="first"></p>
<input type="button" value="UP"  onclick="value_up('first');">
```