# Why object is not proxied like an argument in function

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

i have an interesting example of code that's not working like i'm expected.

I really dont understand why my obj wouldnt proxy.
I'm expect that obj ill proxy via link, but it's not. Can anyone explain how it's works and what I don't understand? Thank you!

```js
let obj = {
  foo: "123"
};

function test(fn, object) {
  object = new Proxy(object, {
    get(target, key) {
      console.log('get');
      return target[key];
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
      console.log('set');
      target[key] = value;
      return true;
    }
  });
  fn();
}

test(() => {
  obj.foo = "helloworld";
  console.log(obj.foo);
}, obj);
```

UPD: i want to assign object to proxy variable ONLY through arguments can i?

Comment: What is `object` did you mean `obj = new Proxy`?

Comment: @Konrad `object` is the argument to `test()`

Answer (score 1):

Either assign the proxy to `obj`

```js
let obj = {
  foo: "123"
};

function test(fn, object) {
  obj = new Proxy(object, {
    get(target, key) {
      console.log('get');
      return target[key];
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
      console.log('set');
      target[key] = value;
      return true;
    }
  });
  fn();
}

test(() => {
  obj.foo = "helloworld";
  console.log(obj.foo);
}, obj);
```

Or pass the proxy as an argument

```js
let obj = {
  foo: "123"
};

function test(fn, object) {
  const o = new Proxy(object, {
    get(target, key) {
      console.log('get');
      return target[key];
    },
    set(target, key, value) {
      console.log('set');
      target[key] = value;
      return true;
    }
  });
  fn(o);
}

test((o) => {
  o.foo = "helloworld";
  console.log(o.foo);
}, obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don’t want to do this, can you explain why this happens, because everything is logical in my opinion and the object should become proxied by reference

Comment: The first solution modifies `obj` permanently, I think they only want the proxy to be in effect during the call to `test()`.

Comment: @user469485 Creating a proxy doesn't modify the object itself. You have to access the properties through the proxy.

Comment: See the examples in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) -- you have to access `proxy2.propertyname`

Comment: The code in the question doesn't work, because an assignment to a parameter doesn't change the original argument.

Comment: @Konrad, As far as i know argument in function will assign by link, so why not?

Comment: @Barmar, I just want to create a proxied object and assign it by link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978392/modify-a-variable-inside-a-function

Comment: @user469485 You can't assign the caller's variable. You need to return the proxy and the caller can assign it to the variable.